# Matlab: coding loops statements to subtract two lines of data

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a data set from the EPA that I have condensed into six columns

[image]

The first column represents different `public water suppliers` (PWS). The second is the `sampleid number`. The third is the `associated sample id number`. Samples with an MR in the beginning of the label indicate an exit point. All other `sample IDs` are entry points with an associated MR. The fourth column is the `sample date`. The fifth is an individual `reference number`. The sixth column is a `sample concentration`.

Essentially what I want to accomplish to match the same `PWS`, the same `date`, and the same `sample ID` and `associate sample id` and finally subtract the difference between the two `sample concentrations` associated with those rows.

My data set is 6 columns by 39000 rows.

*This is the code I have tried:*

```
filename = fopen('Datamine2.csv');
SampleList = textscan(filename,'%s %s %s %s %s %s','Delimiter',',','EmptyValue',0);
fclose(filename);

results = [];
for i = 1:5
    if SampleList{3}{i} ~= 0
        SampleID1 = SampleList{5}{i};
        for j = 1:5
            if SampleList{2}{j} == SampleList{3}{i} && SampleList{1}{j} == SampleList{1}{i} && SampleList{4}{j} == SampleList{4}{i}
                SampleID2 = SampleList{5}{j};
                SampleDiff = str2double(SampleList{6}{i}) - str2double(SampleList{6}{j});
                newresults = [SampleList{1}{i} SampleList{4}{i} SampleDiff SampleID1 SampleID2];
                results = [results;newresults]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

*but this is the error I received:*

> EDU>> run epadata Error using  ==  Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in epadata (line 10)
>               `if SampleList{2}{j} == SampleList{3}{i} && SampleList{1}{j} ==
>               SampleList{1}{i} && SampleList{4}{j} == SampleList{4}{i}`
>
> Error in run (line 64) `evalin('caller', [script ';']);`

Can anyone offer any guidance into solving this? 
Many many thanks.

Comment: Use [MATLAB's debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to verify that all the cells you're using for each comparison are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in `string` format. ( class `char`)

Use [`strcmp()`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) function to compare strings instead of `==` because `==` compares two matrix element-wise and Matrix dimensions must agree for the comparison.

**Example:**

```
>> strcmp('abc','ab')

ans =

 0

>> 'abc' == 'ab'
```

> Error using  `==`
>      Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BJMyers dear Myers, this is the answer, not a critic or clarification request, the problem of his code is that he used == instead of strcmp which generates error when two strings are not equal in size!,  (because == compare two matrix and Matrix dimensions must agree for compare!),

Comment: @darenshan That comment was from review queue and your answer was in the verge of deletion. Just made necessary changes to avoid that. hope you don't mind :)